# LM338T voltage regulator output unstable and fluctuates

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator

Hello guys sorry for my noob question, I have LM388T voltage regulator and i created a module that can supply multiple voltage for 5 components that needed to supplied, i replace potentiometer and use a resistor instead to have a constant output voltage, but there is a problem, 12v is okay and stable,  but 7.2v is unstable and it fluctuates.

- Arduino Mega = 12v
- Solenoid Valve = 12v
- RDS3115 Servo = 7.2v
- MG995 Servo = 7.2v
- GSM Sim900A = 12v

[image]

Comment: Your AC-DC converter block seems wrong. There's no connection between DC 0V and the bridge rectifier. Connect DC 0V to the common anodes of D3-D4. Interestingly, the indicator LEDs too are connected wrong (i.e. anodes are going to DC 0V).

Comment: @RohatKılıç, actually all of the categories there is fine, except voltage regulator. 7.2v is unstable and fluctuating

Comment: I don't care. There's no connection between the DC ground and the bridge rectifier. Don't expect the circuit to work correctly. Please see my updated comment above.

Comment: @unknown. It’s not fine according to your schematic. There is no ground connection in your circuit. It will not work correctly if you built it like your schematic shows.

Comment: also your resistors value are all matching so its wrong also

Comment: Okay2 ill will correct it, i understand thank you guys.

Comment: @unknown i've scanned datasheet there should be minimum current on load (3.5-5mA) .. u probably dont have that on your (7.2) side as led + 4.7K is not drawing current

Comment: ... and 470uF seems to be a too small value for the filter capacitor and its 25V rating is too low if you have 24V secondary voltage at the transformer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you use five LM338 when you could just use two (one for 12 V and another for 7.2V)?

Comment: The regulators are drawn in a very confusing way - normally we would have input on the left, output on the right, and adjust or ground on the bottom of the box.  for a more legible schematic, I'd put the regulators to the right of their fuses, with the regulator outputs going off to the the right. As others say, the LEDs are pointed the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

RDS3115 needs 1.5A on 7.2V, but look into LM338 datasheet and you will see that Icl current limit is 1A for Vin-Vout=30V. Oscilation is result of current limiting (LM338 limits current by lowering output voltage).